# "Largest" class properly contained in PSPACE for a random oracle

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, random-oracles

Green [1] showed that $PP^{PH}$ is properly contained in $PSPACE$ relative to *some* oracle. Around the same time, in the famous "voting polynomials" paper [2], it was shown that $PP$ is properly contained in $PSPACE$ for a *random* oracle.

### Question

> Is it also true that $PP^{PH}$ is properly contained in $PSPACE$ relative to a *random* oracle?

### Observations

1. From what I understand, this can be proved by showing that "small" $AC^{0}$ circuits with a **MAJORITY** gate at the root fail to compute the **PARITY** function even on a (1/2+small)-fraction of inputs. I found such claim in Theorem 6 of [3]. Does this reasoning make sense? Am I interpreting Klivans' theorem in the right way?
2. I wrote "largest" class in the title, because I am also interested in classes that have this same property and that are uncomparable with $PP^{PH}$.

### Motivations

1. Nostalgia for 90s research :)
2. I am looking at similar questions in quantum complexity theory.

### References

1. Frederic Green, [An oracle separating $\oplus P$ from $PP^{PH}$](http://www.clarku.edu/~fgreen/papers/tac.ps), Information Processing Letters, '91
2. James Aspnes, Richard Beigel, Merrick Furst, and Steven Rudich, [The expressive power of voting polynomials](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/papers/stoc91voting-abstract.html), STOC '91
3. Adam Klivans, [On the Derandomization of Constant Depth Circuits](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~klivans/ac3.ps), RANDOM '01

Comment: +1 for nostalgia for 90s research (except it's really kind of 80s-style :)). I think I'll always have a place in my heart for that stuff - I'd always go to my advisor and ask some (80s-style, not that I realized it) question, and he'd always say it was too bad I wasn't a Ph.D. student in the 80s :).

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow I agree with you, oracle complexity is more 80s to be honest, '91 was just the tail of it. Should I create a tag [[80s]]? :P Happy Halloween!

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Oh, and a trick: put a "Quantum" in front of your questions, people will think you're a modern kid :)

Comment: unjustified speculation regarding your title: I imagine that [IP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:I#ip) with a [CH](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:C#ch) verifier is properly contained in PSPACE relative to a random oracle, although I have no idea how one might prove that. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer »IP with a CH verifier« Can you elaborate on what that means?

Comment: That means "the class obtained by replacing 'polynomial-time verifier' from [the definition of IP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:I#ip) with 'verifier in the Counting Hierarchy'". $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer That's what I had understood. Isn't that a much bigger class than IP?

Comment: Well, it's actually equal to IP (since they're both equal to PSPACE), but that equality does not hold with respect to a random oracle. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer I see, thanks for the explanation. Come to think of it, the title doesn't make much sense if I think about IP. I will have to edit it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, because $PP^{PH}=PP$ relative to a random oracle. Follows from [Toda-Ogihara](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0221023)

Comment: Thank you! I wonder if that can be scaled down to some argument about $AC^{0} + MAJ$ circuits vs. voting polynomials.